# SmartGWT mobile Record with SwitchItem

Tags: mobile, smartgwt

I am moderately new to SmartGWT and am trying to figure out how to have a RecordList where each record has the ability to have a SwitchItem attached to it.  So basically create a list of selectable items, but those items also will have a SwitchItem on them to enable/disable some behavior.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Looking at Record and RecordList it appears that Record extends HashMap and does nothing fancy like what I am wanting...but i wondered if it was possible to set the "description" property with perhaps some html string that creates the SwitchItem...is this way off?  And if so...how is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give us more details about what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setShowRecordComponents() and createRecordComponent().  Documentation for how these work can be found in the core SmartGWT docs:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#setShowRecordComponents%28java.lang.Boolean%29

There's no support for "recycle" mode yet.  A sample is being created.